# Android How can i go to the default definitions menu of the Browser

Tags: android, browser, menu, webview

I want to open the definitions browser menu from a button click, without open the browser.

How can i do that ?

thanks

Comment: What is "the definitions browser menu"?

Comment: Sorry, is the menu that opens with the text size, zoom, block popups, etc. When you use the browser, and click the home key.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no "the Browser". Android devices ship with a variety of browsers.

Second, even if we assume that by "the Browser" you mean "the Browser app in the Android Open Source Project that may or may not exist on a device and may or may not be used by the user on a device", there is no documented and supported means of driving directly to that activity.

Comment: so, for example, if i want to put a menu with some functions like the text size, or block popups, i have to make one ? Is not possible to get that activity directly, is this correct ?  Sorry about my bad english and explanation. and Thanks

Comment: @filoli: "if i want to put a menu with some functions like the text size, or block popups, i have to make one ?" -- I have no idea what you are talking about. You are welcome to write your own Web browser app, where you have control over text size and popup blocking, just as many other people have written Web browsers where they are in control over text size and popup blocking.